# Performance of query to find nearest location using latitude and longitude

Tags: mysql, google-maps

I was going through [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?csw=1#findnearsql) article on Google that mentions query to find
nearest location using latitude and longitude. The article and query has been referred by many developers in various forums:

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Their create table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `markers` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
  `name` VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL ,
  `address` VARCHAR( 80 ) NOT NULL ,
  `lat` FLOAT( 10, 6 ) NOT NULL ,
  `lng` FLOAT( 10, 6 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

I was wondering about performance of the query, provided there are hundreds of thousands of records in the table. They have not created any index on any column in table.

1. Will the query scan through all the rows in table?
2. If we index `lat` and `lng` columns would it speed up query execution?
3. Is there any other way to tune this query?

Any inputs will be really appreciated as I am thinking to implement this query as it is in my production code.

Comment: I think you can answer no. 2 yourself

Comment: If I've analyzed the query correct it will just go on computing `distance` for each and every record in the table and will return list of `id`'s having `distance < 25` ? If that's true, indexing won't help here.

Comment: That's true - but it's also clear that for any given point on the Earth, there are a set of latitudes that will fall outside a given radius, so it might be possible to rewrite the query to (crudely) discount latitudes (geographically) higher than latitude + radius and (geographically) lower than latitude - radius.

Comment: That's what I was initially thinking but having that all in single query looks tough (considering distance formula needs both latitude and longitude). Then I found out this example. However, this is not well tuned.